# Soundcloud + SoundManager bug: reading a stream's eqData

Tags: flash, soundcloud, soundmanager2

(This is mainly targeted toward Soundcloud employees because they use Stackoverflow for support)

I've built an app that reads the eqData from a soundcloud stream using soundmanager2:
http://music.freefarm.co.uk/

The eqdata works fine when starting a track, but when seeking or resuming a paused stream, the eqData is no longer updated. Either the array is updated with zeros, or hangs on the previous frame's data.

The app was built almost 6 months and worked correctly, so I'd like to assume it was a change in the soundcloud api. Perhaps due to changes in the flash cross-domain permissions?

Comment: We're not aware of any changes on our side that would break this.
To me it sounds more like an issue in soundManager. Maybe this bug was introduced in soundManager V2.97a.20120318?

Comment: appears to be a security error: SMSound._ondataerror(): data unavailable: SecurityError: Error #2122.. A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.
... is there a specific policy file that we can supply?