# How do I get the metadata from a SoundCloud stream?

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

Using Soundmanager2 to get metadata is hitting troubles with flash permissions. What I want is to access the metadata of a track in order to generate visual effects. (example of which [here](http://reasoner.comoj.com/visual))

One thing I note is that you state

> Their api allows for deep mashups, allowing access to nearly all track
>   meta data

So I know that you intend for this to be possible, in face the presence of [the crossdomain.xml](http://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml) file needed shows this. The problem is that this file only grants permissions for the api subdomain. When a request is made to the api a 3XX response is given, and we are transferred to ec-media.soundcloud.com . This site has no crossdomain.xml file, and so flash and soundmanager hit an error and no metadata is received.

I have found a few instances of this via searching, primarily [SoundCloud + Soundmanager2 + EQData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642556/soundcloud-soundmanager2-eqdata) is exactly the problem I'm having. This question was never answered though, in fact the only responses are from the original poster, and it is left with a hack around the problem.

> My fix is every time I start a song over again I modify the Sound's
>   URL to include a new ts={time} argument and then run .load() on the
>   SMSound which causes a reload and fixes the issue.

So I was wondering why the crossdomain.xml file is omitted on your ec-media subdomain, is it for security reasons? If so why do you state we have access to metadata?

Ultimately, would you be able to put in place the aforementioned file, or will you not and shall we work around the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Hey, thanks for such a thorough explanation of the problem. We'll look at it ASAP and I'll update you with how we resolve this.

Comment: Hey, yes, it will be enabled soon, I'll write an update when it is. sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[crossdomain.xml](http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml) is now available for everyone. I am sorry it took so long.

Comment: Actually, one question, what roughly is the expiration on the ec-media link? It gives a UNIX timestamp which is 5 minutes away, but I can still use that link to play hours later